# encoding issue with ñ

Tags: c#, asp.net, encoding

I have an issue with encoding.

Take the following spanish word: niño

When I include it in a filename, when outputted on screen it gets outputted as: ni%c3%b1o

How can I encode or do necessary so that niño is outputted in the html? I develop in .net c#.

Comment: file encoding and the encoding you defined for your website must match?

Comment: For what it's worth, `%c3%b1` is the UTF-8 encoding of `ñ`.

Comment: Can you show how it is being outputted to the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this [page](http://webdesign.about.com/library/bl_htmlcodes.htm) has a list of encodes for non standard IE not English characters.  In general you can use the character code value of the character perpended by &#(x)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using IE? I've seen that bug when using it. Doesn't happen with other browsers like FF or Chrome, not an ASP.Net bug or something you can avoid.

I don't know if it happens with IE 9 tho. If you look around in your favourite search engine, you'll find several sites with workarounds for this problem. Eg: [Some Google's results](http://www.google.es/search?q=ie%20utf-8%20filename%20encoding).

I once used one I found online, and worked like a charm, but cannot remember how it was exactly.